# Indexing Method on Object Returned From Method - Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I'm using the `elasticsearch-rails` gem with `Rails 6`. I'm trying to index the return value of a carrierwave function `asset_host`. I can index the `file` function, but I'm not sure of the syntax to index the `asset_host` method on the `Uploader` object returned by `file.

From my model, I can access the function with the following code:

```
Asset.first.file.asset_host
```

I've added the `asset_host` file to my mapping with this code:

```
indexes :file do
    indexes :asset_host, type: "text"
end
```

And this is my attempt to add the method to the `as_indexed_json` function which is where I'm having issues:

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json(methods: {file: [:asset_host]})
end
```

Here is the error I am getting with this code for `as_indexed_json` when I try to reindex my documents:

```
TypeError ([:file, [:asset_host]] is not a symbol nor a string)
```

I guess this functionality isn't supported? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an `as_json` problem. Maybe you could try

```
as_json(
  only: [],  # exclude all "normal" attributes
  include: {file: {only: :asset_host}}
)
```